# PUT Form doesn't Update In Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony

I have a form with `PUT` method

```
{{ form(formEdit, {'action': path('user_update',{'id':user.id}), 'method': 'PUT'}) }}
```

And My Action is

```
/**
     * Edits an existing User entity.
     *
     * @Route("/{id}", name="user_update")
     * @Method("PUT")
     * @Template("foo:User:update.html.twig")
     * @ParamConverter("User", class="foo:User")
     */
    public function updateAction(Request $request,User $user){
        $form = $this->createForm(new UserType(), $user);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($user);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('user',array('id' => $user->getId())));
        }


        return array(
            'formEdit' => $form->createView(),
            'user' => $user
        );
    }
```

My Twig

```
{{ form(formEdit, {'action': path('user_update',{'id':user.id}),'method':'PUT'}) }}
```

When I Submitted the form, I haven't any errors. 
If I Change PUT with POST, the form works.
I tried with

```
    echo $request->getMethod();
    echo $form->getErrorsAsString();
```

and this is my output

```
PUT
name: No errors surname: No errors email: No errors gender: 0: No errors 1: No errors submit: No errors name: No errors surname: No errors email: No errors gender: 0: No errors 1: No errors submit: No errors
```

But I don't understand how can i Catch that error. I'm using Symfony 2.3

Comment: Why don't you use POST and pass this problem?

Comment: Because i'd like to use PUT for update, like REST API http://restcookbook.com/HTTP%20Methods/put-vs-post/

Comment: Can you please add the code that shows how the form is rendered in your twig template?

Comment: See [How to Use HTTP Methods beyond GET and POST in Routes](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/method_parameters.html). Check [http_method_override parameter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#configuration-framework-http-method-override).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forms can handle only POST and GET requests. You can see [here](https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=10671) why PUT and DELETE have not been added as form methods.

You can send PUT requests only through AJAX calls.

Comment: Thanks, but If i use `php  app/console generate:doctrine:crud` Symfony creates all methods to manage users (for example) In its methods there are even PUT, and it's works. My Code is the same, but doesn't work

Comment: Symfony2 will mimic PUT behavior, adding an hidden _method field. OP question is valid